# Randomly sampling from each element of a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a numeric vector `X`

```
X <- c(1,42,1,23,5,7)
```

I would like to create another vector `Y` with the same number of elements, each of which is a randomly generated whole number from a sequence in which 1 is the lower bound and the element in `X` is the upper bound e.g for `Y[2]` the number would be a randomly generated number selected from between 1 and 42 and for `Y[4]` the number would be randomly selected from between 1 and 23.

I have tried to use the apply function to do this

```
Y<-apply(C, 1, sample)
```

but I am having no luck and generating the error message

> Error in apply(X, 1, sample) : dim(X) must have a positive length1,
>   sample

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `apply` for a vector, but for multidimensional objects only (e.g., matrices). You have to use `sapply` instead. Futhermore, you need the argument `size = 1` since you want to sample one value for each entry of `X`.

```
sapply(X, sample, size = 1)
[1]  1  7  1 16  3  6
```